# Is there a way to cast a group of columns to the same NUMBER(p,s) type so that they can be UNPIVOT in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table several numeric columns all with different `NUMBER(p,s)` types. The table was created with a `CREATE TABLE xx as (select date, SUM(x), SUM(y) from xxx GROUP BY date)`. It seems that snowflake decided the minimum `NUMBER(precision, scale)` required to store each resulting column. That resulting in different types for each column.

Now I want to UNPIVOT those columns and Snowflake will complain that `SQL compilation error: The type of column 'xxxxx' conflicts with the type of other columns in the UNPIVOT list`

I create this little minimal table to exemplify the problem:

```
create or replace temporary table temp1(id number, sales number(10,0), n_orders number(20,0)) as (
    select * from (values
           (1, 1, 2 )
           ,(2, 3, 4)
           ,(3, 5, 6)
    ) 
); -- imagine that temp1 was created via a select AGG1, AGG2 FROM XXX GROUP BY YYY

describe table temp1;
-- 
name    type    kind    null?   default primary key unique key  check   expression  comment
ID  NUMBER(38,0)    COLUMN  Y       N   N           
SALES   NUMBER(10,0)    COLUMN  Y       N   N           
N_ORDERS    NUMBER(20,0)    COLUMN  Y       N   N           

select * 
from temp1 UNPIVOT(measure_value for measure_name in (sales, n_orders)); -- won't work because SALES is NUMBER(10,0) and N_ORDERS is NUMBER(20,0)
```

Right now my workaround is to cast each columns with a explicit `TO_NUMBER(x, 38,0) as x` like so:

```
with t1 as (
  select 
    id
    ,TO_NUMBER(sales,38,0) as sales
    ,TO_NUMBER(n_orders, 38,0) as n_orders
  from temp1
)
select * from t1 UNPIVOT(measure_value for measure_name in (sales, n_orders));
```

This is less than optimal because there are many columns in the actual table that I'm using.

I don't want to recreate the table (the aggregations take long to compute) so what are my options?

Is there a any other syntax that I can use to cast in bulk a list of columns?

Comment: It should be noted that there is no storage or performance costs in Snowflake related to defining anything other than NUMBER(38,0) or just NUMBER with no (p,s).  There are end-user BI tools that sometimes increase their storage based on these values, but as far as Snowflake is concerned, there is no reason to constrain the length of your numbers.  This is true with VARCHAR, as well.

Comment: Yes, but Snowflake automatically selects different NUMBER(p,s) for different aggregations. I did not select myself `NUMBER(30,0)` or `NUMBER(31,0)`.  I just did a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE xxx AS SELECT ID, MAX(xxx) as b, MIN(yyy) as c FROM zzz GROUP BY ID` and the resulting b and c column had different `NUMBER(p,s)`

Comment: What were the data types of xxx and yyy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to modify the already create table (without having to rerun the costly aggregation) like so:

```
alter table temp1 modify
  sales set data type number(38,0)
  ,n_orders set data type number(38,0)
;
```

This way has two advantages:

1. you avoid typing the column name twice for each column:  `column_name set data type number(38,)` instead of `TO_NUMBER(column_name, 38,0) as column_name`
2. It's run just once, instead of having to running as a CTE before each UNPIVOT query.